# How to change scrollbar position?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, position

Is it possible to change the scrollbar position when the user reaches a certain point scrolling down a web page? For example once you reached half way down down the page the scrollbar would move automatically back to the top.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage of the current position of the scrollbar using the [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll) event, and if it reaches the 50 % the scroll position can be set to the top of the page with the [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) function:

```
window.onload = function () { 
  window.onscroll = function () { 
    var doc = document.body, 
    scrollPosition = doc.scrollTop,
    pageSize = (doc.scrollHeight - doc.clientHeight),
    percentageScrolled = Math.floor((scrollPosition / pageSize) * 100); 

     if (percentageScrolled >= 50){ // if the percentage is >= 50, scroll to top
       window.scrollTo(0,0); 
     } 
   }; 
};
```

You can check my example [here](http://jsbin.com/eqote).

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,0); 
 doesn't work for me in chomre

Answer (score 13):

Yup, I've seen it a few times. Here is some JS code:

```
window.scrollBy(0,50)
```

50 is the amount of pixels you want to scroll by.

Answer (score 4):

The three scrolling functions you'll want to concern yourself with are `window.scroll(x,y)`, `window.scrollBy(dx,dy)`, and `window.scrollTo(x,y)`.

As David mentioned you'll need the scroll position to know where you are and use the `window.onscroll` event to fire off this calculation.

Comment: Are these available on all browsers or is some feature detection required?

Answer (score 2):

(window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop) ought to give you the current scroll position in just about any browser.