# How does the Facebook scrollbar work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

On Facebook the document scrollbar takes control of the message container when a message is recieved.

**Question:**
How can I re-create this functionality?

Comment: Facebook is rendered using a very very complicated JavaScript Framework. I think you should leave it at that.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh yes, i guess so but maybe someone knows how to make that trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can decipher from your message, I believe this will answer your question:
[Changing Scrollbar Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247874/changing-scrollbar-position)

You should also take a look at jQuery's scrollTo (plugin) function:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Sorry for my bad presentation and also my bad English.
I try to make it with the scrollTo function but i couldn't make the same effect. The only think that works is to replace the scrollbar with a jQuery made one like jScrollPane, with that you can control the relative position of the div without change the document position.

Thanks !

Comment: Does the above answer your question? If so I will edit your question to make it more suitable.

Comment: not completely but helps anyway! Thanks!!
(I press the 'Enter' to make a new line and it post the comment, sorry for that)

Comment: I will give you a +1 because you're new and -6 on your question is a bit harsh! Just try to improve your question clarity next time ;)