# css overscroll scroll to position

Tags: html, css, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Scrollbar Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247874/changing-scrollbar-position)

I have a div that will act like an image browser

```
<div style="width:100%; height:500px; overflow:auto;">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="news" style="width:100%;height:auto;"/>
</div>
```

if my image is 1200px in height, is there anyway that i can predefine the scrolling position of the image? basically scroll to the middle part of the image when the page loads

i'm not looking for an jQuery scrolling animation plugin. I want the page to load with the image already scrolled to a specific position.

my main audience would be using various versions of IE....(> IE7)

Comment: That is jQuery, but not any scrolling animation plugin so in my book that is a working solution.

Comment: @Henrik OK so please find my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('#foo').scrollTop(500);
```

Pure JS

```
 document.getElementById('foo').scrollTop = 500; // (working with IE6+)
```

More information find here:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t35

Answer (score 1):

use scrollTo(0, window height * 0.5);
or if you need you can calculate the current div's center relative to the page offset.