# How do I get this scroll - triggered effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is this site http://lamoulade.com/#!/home with neat pseudo-animation effect that kicks in when user is scrolling. If i could get a few pointers on what is used in order to achieve that just to push me in the right research direction, I would be most grateful. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for, a tutorial with a few different methods.  He calls it "Parallax", which might help you find what you're looking for.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/parallax/

Comment: This SO thread [Changing Scrollbar Position](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247874/137626) should help you for the most basic JS involved.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: @JimmyRare: What a pointless comment.

Comment: @Dutchie432 What does that make yours and even this comment? =D

Comment: The linked site no longer functions.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking is called `parallax Effect`

Some parallax tutorials:

- http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html
- http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/jquery-vertical-parallax-background/
- http://www.richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/background.html
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/
- http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/building-parallax-scrolling-storytelling-framework
- http://www.webdesignshock.com/one-page-website/
- http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/
- http://www.franckmaurin.com/the-parallax-effects-with-jquery/

jQuery parallax plugins:

- http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html
- http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin
- https://github.com/davecranwell/jQuery-scroll-parallax
- http://www.davecranwell.com/content/jquery-scroll-parallax-plugin

Some more examples of really nice parallax sites, view source and see what they used:

- http://www.ok-studios.de/home/
- http://www.nikebetterworld.com/about
- http://www.laurentiuswonen.com/jaarverslag2010/
- http://www.nintendo.com.au/gamesites/mariokartwii/
- http://2011.beercamp.com/
- http://www.beetle.com/
- http://activatedrinks.com/
- http://www.culturalsolutions.co.uk/
- http://kalendiar.lenm.cz/
- http://www.davegamache.com/sandbox/best-of-2010/
- https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT

Taken From Good Answer from [DBUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898416/dbuk)

Comment: Thanks guys, this will put me in the right direction. Have a pleasant evening.

Comment: Many of these reference links are gone.